# python finditer functionality in r language?

Tags: python, r, regex, python-3.x

I am python programmer and i want to use regular expression in r, but i want the functionality of [`finditer`](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/10/python-finditer-regular-expression/) in r language , not findall , i want to use each value something like:

so if i have a file which contains:

```
<LayerDepth Units="mm" Count="4" value1="141" value2="241" value3="1104" value4="1492" value444="898" LastModified="6/11/2012"
```

Now if i use this piece of code :

```
import re
pattern='(value\d.+?)"(\d.+?)"'
with open("file1.txt",'r') as f:
    match=re.finditer(pattern,f.read())
    for i in match:
        print(i.group())
```

output will be:

```
value1="141"
value2="241"
value3="1104"
value4="1492"
value444="898"
```

I want same functionality in r , How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `gregexpr` with the following pattern:

```
(value\d+="\d+")
```

Then, use `regmatches` with the output of `gregexpr` to obtain the actual matches from the input string.

```
x <- c("<LayerDepth Units=\"mm\" Count=\"4\" value1=\"141\" value2=\"241\" value3=\"1104\" value4=\"1492\" value444=\"898\" LastModified=\"6/11/2012\" Now")
m <- gregexpr("(value\\d+=\"\\d+\")", x)
regmatches(x, m)
[[1]]
[1] "value1=\"141\""   "value2=\"241\""   "value3=\"1104\""  "value4=\"1492\"" 
[5] "value444=\"898\""
```

### Demo

Comment: but for that i have to change my regular expression ? i have a large code in python using three patterns,

Comment: @toy_sta I have given you a working answer with a demo.  If you want to stick with your Python script, that is fine as well.

Comment: Actually the code in this answer does work with the pattern in the question: `regmatches(x, gregexpr('(value\\d.+?)"(\\d.+?)"', x))`